# Can anyone explain how this memory leak in Java/Android works in detail?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, classloader

I have been doing Java development for a long time, but I am ashamed to say I still don't have a good grasp on how memory leaks actually takes place. I however have no experience with Android development.

Take the following code for example taken from [this presentation](https://youtu.be/6ryAYxLNpt8?t=787):

[image]

I have the following questions (please note that I am new to Android, but this example is not primarily focused on Android)

1. How is memory leak even possible here ? The author says that its because the inner class is not marked as `static` and it will hold a reference to the outer class.

So if I keep creating objects of the outer class like so:

```
MainActivity one = new MainActivity();
one.onCreate(bundle);

MainActivity two = new MainActivity();
two.onCreate(bundle);

MainActivity three = new MainActivity();
three.onCreate(bundle);
```

How does it matter ? If I am not wrong about how `static` references work, then only one object of `LeakClass` is created, right? Unless a separate `classloader` is involved, right?

2. Is the memory leak only possible here because of how Android works? If I were to manually create these objects then this would not be a problem, right?

Comment: I don't know Android either so I'm not 100% sure. But I know Java as well, and in your sample code, only one instance of LeakClass will be created (when you create the instance one), no matter how many more new MainActivity() you create. And when I read the comments left under the video you posted (which I didn't watch entirely so I can't really judge)... well... I don't know if I'd trust there's really a memory leak here.

Comment: The leak is from the first `MainActivity` instance that can't be garbage-collected after it's been effectively destroyed by the system, because it's still tied to that `LeakClass` instance. Android recreates `Activity` classes quite a bit – e.g., upon a device rotation, by default – so you can go through several different instances of `MainActivity` in one session. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also, I realize that it might just be illustrative, but I would mention that you should never directly instantiate `Activity` classes yourself; the system must handle that.

Comment: @MikeM. Just one question - there is just one `MainActivity` being stored in the static field correct ?

Comment: There is only one _instance_ of `MainActivity` that's tied to the one instance of `LeakClass` stored in the static field, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Because LeakClass is an inner class, it has an inherent reference to the instance of the outer class that owns it.  Since you're storing that value in a static variable, that means you're storing a reference to the outer class in that static transitively.  Storing an Activity in a static is ALWAYS a leak, and ALWAYS a bad idea.  Activities aren't singletons, you cannot assume there will only be one of them.

If you don't need that parent reference, you can make it a static inner class.  Static inner classes do not have an implicit outer reference, but cannot access member variables of functions of the owning class.  Or you can make it a standalone, non-inner class (the two are equally good solutions).

If you do need that parent reference, you cannot store it in a static variable without a leak. Figure out another way to make that data available.

Comment: So there is only one reference of the `MainActivity` class being stored correct ?